# get size of blob storage GCP

Tags: python, google-cloud-storage, airflow, blob

I'm working with python and airflow(composer)

I have many csv files in a GCP bucket and I need to get the size of a particular file.

The file name comes from before.
I am using the list_blobs function but I have to use a for to search for the file, isn't there a function to obtain the information of a particular blob?

```
 from google.cloud.storage import Blob
 from google.cloud import storage

 client = storage.Client()
 bucket = client.bucket('gs://bucket_name')
 desired_file = kwargs['csv_name']

  for blob in bucket.list_blobs():
    if desired_file== blob.name and blob.size > 0:
        print("Name: "+ blob.name +" Size blob obj: "+str(blob.size) + "bytes")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can utilize the function `bucket.get_blob('filename')` to get a desired blob instead of looping through `bucket.list_blobs()`.

```
from google.cloud.storage import Blob
from google.cloud import storage

client = storage.Client()
bucket = client.bucket('gs://bucket_name')
desired_file = kwargs['csv_name']

# new code
blob = bucket.get_blob(desired_file)

print("Name: "+ blob.name +" Size blob obj: "+str(blob.size) + "bytes")
```